# How to mute this error or disable the inspection in WebStorm or PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

#### On Further Inspection (2019.10.07)

The problem is not limited to the error I originally saw. I think it stems from the fact that the IDE (or is it an Angular service?) is parsing and checking what's within `<textarea>` as if it were regular HTML whereas textarea content is really just raw text.  The right approach might be to just consider everything inside `<textarea>` as a literal string.

#### Original Question

In PhpStorm, I am developing an Angular project.  When in the template I use the open curly braces within a textarea like so:

```
<textarea>
  {}
</textarea>
```

I get the error:

> Unterminated expansion form.  If you have unescaped '{', use '{{"{"}}' to escape it.

Assuming this `{` doesn't make the actual HTML invalid, I would like to mute this error or disable the inspection that generates it.  Is that possible? If there is a way in WebStorm, it will probably also work in PhpStorm

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error can't be suppressed unfortunately.
Please vote for [WEB-41745](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-41745) to be notified on any progress with it